# assigning varieties to plots

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, solution-verification

> Suppose we have $a$ varieties of a certain crop and an $a\times a$ grid of plots. Each variety has $a$ occurrences. We call a randomized block design a random assignment of varieties such that each variety appears once in every row of the grid. What is the probability that for a randomly chosen assignment, some variety will appear in the same position in each row? Given a randomized block design, what is the probability that some variety will appear in the same position in each row?

I'm not sure whether I've dealt with this general case properly. We consider the random case first. For $1\leq k < a,$ there are ${a\choose k}^2\cdot k!$ to choose $k$ varieties and order them into $k$ rows, where each of the $k$ varieties occurs in the same position in each row. There are then $\prod_{i=k}^{a-1} {a(a-i)\choose a}$ ways to choose the remaining varieties, as there are ${a(a-i)\choose a}$ ways to choose the $a$ occurrences of variety $i$ (as we've already chosen $a\cdots i$ of the plots). Also, there are $a!$ ways to select $a$ varieties that occur in the same position in each row. This gives a total of
$\sum_{k=1}^{a-1} (-1)^{k+1} {a\choose k}^2 \cdot k! \cdot \prod_{i=k}^{a-1} {a(a-i)\choose a} + (-1)^{a+1}a!$. Observe that the total number of cases is $\prod_{i=0}^{a-1} {a(a-i)\choose a}$ as initially we can select $a$ varieties from the $a\times a$ grid and after $i$ selections, we have $a\times (a-i)$ plots to choose the $a$ varieties. Hence the desired probability is $\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{a-1} \left((-1)^{k+1} {a\choose k}^2 \cdot k! \cdot \prod_{i=k}^{a-1} {a(a-i)\choose a}\right) + (-1)^{a+1}a!}{\prod_{i=0}^{a-1} {a(a-i)\choose a}}$

For the randomized block design question, we first compute the number of randomized block designs. This number is $(a!)^a,$ as there are $a!$ ways to arrange the $a$ varieties in each row. Now we compute the number of ways to select $k$ varieties that each occur in the same position in each row. Using similar logic to above, there are ${a\choose k}^2\cdot k!$ ways to do this. For the other varieties, there are $((a-k)!)^a$ possibilities, $(a-k)!$ per row, for $a$ rows. This gives a total of

$\sum_{k=1}^a (-1)^{k+1} {a\choose k}^2 \cdot k! ((a-k)!)^a$ possibilities.  Hence the desired probability is $\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^a (-1)^{k+1} {a\choose k}^2 \cdot k! ((a-k)!)^a}{(a!)^a}$.

> Is this correct? And if so, would there be a faster way? Btw, I implicitly used the fact that in the general case, with $k$ intersections, we alternate between including and excluding them to ensure each part is included once.